# How can I receive a JSON in symfony2

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, symfony

I'm currently working on a symfony2 based project with lots of ajax usage.

Now I want to send a JSON via `$.ajax();` (POST type) and handle it in a symfony2 controller.
But I'm not quite sure how I access the JSON inside the controller.

Right now I've got the following:

JS:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:"POST",
                data:json,
                success:function (data) {
                    $('div.tooltip p').html(data);
                }
            });
```

And the PHP:

```
    public function registrationAction(Request $request) {
        if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            // How to receive??
        }

        return $this->render('KnowHowERegistrationBackendBundle:Create:registration.html.twig');
}
```

The only thing I don't know is how can I access the JSON?
I'm sure it's pretty easy I just don't see it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should take a look at the FOSRestBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code i think not complete,if you want to send data to server with json format i think the setup $.ajax like this, just example

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:"POST",
                data:"JSONFile=" + json,
                success:function (data) {
                    $('div.tooltip p').html(data);
                }
            });
```

add parameter JSONFile or whatever what do you want.and you can use json decode to retrive json from client.

this is code in php:

```
$json = $_POST['JSONFile'];

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true)); //true option if you will convert to array
```

in  symfony2 controller direct acces `$_POST` is bad so use request
`$request = $this->getRequest();`
`$request->request->get('JSONFile'); // get a $_POST parameter`

Comment: While this works and is uncomplicated, accessing `$_POST` directly is not a good way to do it with Symfony 2. The answer from jBinfo is much better.

Comment: yup my code just example in php, in Sysmfony 2 maybe to get parameters and prefer hight security that will be different case. to get parameter you can use `$request->request->get('JSONFile'); // get a $_POST parameter`

Answer (score 15):

in your ajax request u must set the content type to application/json:

```
$.ajax({
      url: url,
      type:"POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data:json,
      success:function (data) {
           $('div.tooltip p').html(data);
      }
});
```

and in your controller use this to parse the content:

```
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `$request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());`
See api [here](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) for methods used on $request object.